# Scraping GIS coordinates from a non-traditional map using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, gis

I'm trying to scrape a website with real estate publications. Each publication looks like this:

https://www.portalinmobiliario.com/venta/casa/providencia-metropolitana/5427357-francisco-bilbao-amapolas-uda#position=5&type=item&tracking_id=cedfbb41-ce47-455d-af9f-825614199c5e

I have been able to extract all the information I need except the coordinates (GIS) of the publications. The maps appear to be pasted (not linked). Does anyone know how to do this?

please help

Im using selenium/python3.

Comment: Where is your code and which browser are you using?

Comment: Also link which you have provided is not working

Answer (score 0):

Im using Selenium & Chrome.

This is the list of publications:

https://www.portalinmobiliario.com/venta/casa/propiedades-usadas/las-condes-metropolitana

If you click any property of that list, it will take to the page were the maps are displayed. I'm using a loop to go through all of them (one at a time).

The code is a bit long, but so far i have been mostly using find_element_by_class_name and find_element_by_xpath to find and extract the information. I tried using them for the map but I dont know where to find the coordinates.